# What is the origin of the word digicam? When and where did it originate?

Tags: etymology

Supposedly the word digicam (digital camera) originated in 1989 as a trade name in England, but I have not found any further information.

Comment: Personally, I've not seen *digicam* used frequently. Maybe more so back when film cameras were ubiquitous and digital cameras a novelty? (Today, the opposite is mostly true.)

Comment: It was the name used when   the first  digital camera became available on the market in those years. Just ***digi*** ( digital) ***cam*** ( camera) to distinguish them from non digital products.

Comment: Built by Ampex in our new California facilities, the Digicam was designed to produce the highest quality picture both on location and in the studio. A Computer In a Portable Head. The BCC-20 Digicam's computer-in-thehead technology ...(1980) https://www.google.it/search?q=%22digicam%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1980,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=c6eOVfqYI4WssAGNhIboDA

Answer (score 1):

The [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/digicam) offers the following definition of *digicam*:

> **digicam** *n. Informal* A digital camera.

However, the first occurrences of the word *digicam* in a Google Books search results use the term to refer to a TV videocamera for shooting videotape.

Here is the Ngram chart for *digicam* for the period 1970–2005:

[image]

The three earliest instances of *digicam* (short for "digital videocamera") that a Google Books search finds are from 1980—and all three refer to videocameras manufactured by Ampex (of Redwood City, California) that debuted in 1979. From [*Filmmakers*](https://books.google.com/books?id=B2Y7AAAAMAAJ&q=%22digicam%22&dq=%22digicam%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pT-PVbvmFMrFogS9n4KYBQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBjgK), volume 14 (1980) [combined snippets]:

> Internal circuitry compares the camera's current operating conditions with a previously established set of operating parameters, and automatically adjusts the camera to optimum settings. Ikegami and Hitachi offer computer set-up as options on their top-of-the-line studio cameras. Ampex offers the BCC-14 **Digicam**, which is a computer controlled ENG/EFP camera. While a computer set-up camera is expensive to purchase initially, time and manpower savings make such a system attractive to high volume production facilities.

From an Ampex advertisement in [*Broadcasting Cable Yearbook*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DrkWAQAAMAAJ&q=%22digicam%22&dq=%22digicam%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pT-PVbvmFMrFogS9n4KYBQ&ved=0CC8Q6AEwATgK) (1980) [combined snippets]:

> **THE BCC-20 DIGICAM.**
>
> Our new EFP camera features computer-in-the-head technology that combines a microprocessor and digital memory with a powerful software program for full-time video control of the camera.
>
> **Digicam** can achieve 0.06% registration in all zones of the TV picture quickly in addition to giving the operator automatic or manual set-up with results that surpass those of a conventional camera.

And in an Ampex advertisement from [*International Broadcast Engineer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5bUpAQAAMAAJ&q=%22BCC-20+Digicam%27s+computer-in-thehead+technology+%22&dq=%22BCC-20+Digicam%27s+computer-in-thehead+technology+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=40WPVfCEOsO1oQS1nY2QCA&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ), volumes 170–190 (1980[?]) [combined snippets], cited by Josh61 in a comment above:

> Built by Ampex in our new California facilities, the **Digicam** was designed to produce the highest quality picture both on location and in the studio A Computer In a Portable Head. The BCC-20 **Digicam's** computer-in-the-head technology combines a microprocessor and digital memory with a powerful software program to give you full-time digital control of the camera.
>
> Even with the power turned off the **Digicam's** memory-on-the-head stores the operating parameters.

The [TV Camera Museum](http://www.tvcameramuseum.org/ampex/ampexthumbnails.htm) confirms that the Ampex BCC-14 ("Portable Colour," according to the site) was released circa 1980, and the Ampex BCC-20 ("Portable ENG Colour") in 1980. Various Ampex Digicams are mentioned in publications throughout the early 1980s.

Though the drop-off in frequency of use of the term *digicam* since 2003 (indicated in the Ngram graph above) may be exaggerated by incomplete data, I suspect that, as cell phones have become more and more capable of handling video and photography, the consumer market for digital cameras and videocameras (sometimes called *camcorders*) has waned. For its part, Ampex went out of business in October 2014, according to the [Wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampex).

Comment: The Ampex product you describe sounds like a digitally-controlled camera, not a digital-image camera. It would be interesting to know when, if ever, D(d)igicam came to refer to digital-image cameras, whether still or motion.